# "EffectiveUserName' XML for Analysis property is not valid" error when refreshing from SSAS gateway

Tags: powerbi, ssas, gateway

We have a very simple Power BI report which connects to a SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Service) Tabular model, using an import query.

The goal is to have this published to our workspace, and have it refresh daily. To accomplish this, we've:

- Created a Windows Service Account

  Added that Windows service account to the SSAS tabular model, with Full Control (administator)

  Added the SSAS server/Tabular model to the gateway, using the above service account - No issues

  Set up the gateway connection in the Dataset details - No issues

[image]

However, when we try and refresh the dataset (either manually/or scheduled), it generates the ""EffectiveUserName' XML for Analysis property is not valid" error, and refresh fails.

Any ideas?

```
Data source error: {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","pbi.error":
{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","parameters":{},"details":[
{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},
{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"AnalysisServices: 
The 'FirstName@CompanyDomain.ca' value of the 'EffectiveUserName' XML for Analysis property is not valid."}},
{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},
{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind","detail":{"type":1,"value":"AnalysisServices"}},
{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath","detail":{"type":1,"value":"ssasServer123\\tabular;SalesDataModel"}},
{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason","detail":{"type":1,"value":"DataSource.Error"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}} 
Table: FactDataSales.
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to make the windows service account a SSAS admin (of the SSAS instance not the database) which is required to perform EffectiveUserName impersonation.

Also check that the FirstName@CompanyDomain.ca has been given access to query the tabular model and that this email matches their UPN in the on prem AD. You can run `whoami /upn` from a command prompt to confirm your UPN.

Comment: Ah okay! Unfortunately we only have security to add users at the data model level. Our IT is unwilling to add the Service account at the instance level.

Comment: @DepthofField maybe the security team can create a new service account and make it an SSAS instance admin and enter the credentials into the Power BI gateway data source foe you and not tell you the password?

Comment: Haha! I actually proposed that. They just don't like the idea of ANY service account having full admin (even if Business users don't have direct access), but they also do not like the idea of Power BI hitting their analysis cubes/tabular models. They will only okay if/when we move to Azure cloud.